# Execute a new set of fetches only after the earlier set has ran trough

Tags: javascript, oop, promise, fetch

I'm trying to fetch images for a live camera feed web page from an API. The problem is that with just timed fetch request, eventually one of the API responds takes so long that the code errors. The page has multiple camera feeds that are simultaneously refreshing with the loop for all the cameras in the cameraObjects[] array. The image() function should respond with a resolve that would then be collected in to an array promises[].

Put simply I need to run the refreshImages() function when ALL the image() functions called by the loop in updateImages() have been ran. I have just started coding so bare with me...

```
class camera {
    constructor(Uuid,url,username,password) {
        this.Uuid = Uuid;
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    image() {

        let uuid = this.Uuid
        let url = this.url
        let username = this.username
        let password = this.password
        let headers = new Headers();
        let authString = `${username}:${password}`; 
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(authString));
        let imageUrl = url + uuid
        fetch(imageUrl,{method: 'GET', headers: headers})
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(image => {
                console.log(image);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                        var base64data = reader.result;                
                        let img = document.getElementById("camera_" + uuid);
                        img.src = base64data;
                        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                                resolve(promise);
                        })

                }
            })
    }
        
} 
function updateImages() {
    cameraObjects = listOfCameraObjects();
    let promises = [];
    for(let e = 0; e < cameraObjects.length; e++) {
        let promise = new Promise(cameraObjects[e].image())
        promises.push(promise)
    }
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(() => { 
            refreshImages();
        })
}
function refreshImages() {
    let currentInterval = getInterval();
    refrehInterval = setTimeout(updateImages, currentInterval);
    console.log(refrehInterval)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few things you're doing wrong with Promises -

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(promise);
})
```

That's sort of OK though `return Promise.resolve(promise)` is identical - however in your code, what is `promise`? not declared anywhere in that scope - also, as the last code in an event handler (onloadend) it is pointless, since returning a value from an event handler is meaningless

```
let promise = new Promise(cameraObjects[e].image())
```

that's not how you construct a promise ... the argument to the promise constructor needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function (unless that returns a function, of course, but it doesn't)

I'd suggest you perhaps read some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) about how you construct a Promise, and how you then use them

In the meantime, I believe this code will do what you want

```
class camera {
    constructor(Uuid,url,username,password) {
        this.Uuid = Uuid;
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    image() {
        const headers = new Headers();
        const authString = `${this.username}:${this.password}`; 
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(authString));
        const imageUrl = this.url + this.Uuid;
        
        return fetch(imageUrl, {method: 'GET', headers: headers})
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(image => new Promise((resolve, reject) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
                const img = document.getElementById("camera_" + uuid);
                img.src = reader.result;
                resolve();
            });
            reader.addEventListener('error', reject);
        }));
    }
        
} 
function updateImages() {
    Promise.all(listOfCameraObjects().map(cam => cam.image()))
    .then(refreshImages);
}
function refreshImages() {
    let currentInterval = getInterval();
    refrehInterval = setTimeout(updateImages, currentInterval);
    console.log(refrehInterval)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and thank you for simplifying the code! Now it doesn't send a new request before the earlier one has returned. Although I'm not sure if the setTimeout() is working correctly. If I change the currentInterval it just piles the requests after another. If I check the refreshInterval value after a few requests, its value has changed to some integer that keeps adding up. ClearInterval() or just declaring it as null doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Wifimies `refrehInterval ` is the "id" of the setTimeout, you use this to clearTimeout to stop the timeout before it triggers - no idea why you refer to ClearInterval ,,, since you're (correctly) using a timeout rather than an interval ... what does getInterval return?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've been using both since neither one seems to work. getInterval() returns an integer (100,200,300,500 or 1000) which can be selected by the user. If the user changes the value, the different setTimeout()s get piled on top of each other.                   
if(!timer) {timer = setTimeout(updateImages(), currentInterval); }          
clearTimeout(timer); console.log(timer) //logs (1,2,3,4,5...)                                                                                                        
timer = null; console.log(timer) //logs(null)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "piled on top of each other" - each setTimeout returns a new, distinct number ... I note that your comment you have `setTimeout(updateImages(), currentInterval)` ... which of course is NOT what the code I wrote is doing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62465322/16349748 I used this as reference, I thought setTimeout and setInterval work in a similar manner here and the question seemed to have the same problem. I mean that if I change the value coming from getInterval(), the different setTimeout()s keep executing and eventually there are thousands of requests every second.

Comment: `setTimeout(updateImages(), currentInterval)` is not the same as `setTimeout(updateImages, currentInterval)`

Comment: Welp, once again I seemed to have somehow mixed it when I was testing it and indeed that was the problem. Now it seems to work just how it was intended, you are a life saver for a beginner like me:). When I tested the code you wrote I was calling the refreshImages() in a another functions which was causing double requests...